# Change the input and output font/size/color in the terminal?

Tags: terminal, command, color-scheme

Tried searching, but couldn't find what I was looking for. Perhaps, my wording. Anyway:

What I basically want to do is make it easier for me to differentiate my input and the output in the terminal. Both colors font style look the same in my terminal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) in your output.  That wikipedia link provides a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find something similar to what I was looking for: http://snag.gy/P9BvM.jpg

I wanted to change the command color as well but couldn't find that one. Anyway: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt

I will see if I can modify the input color, which would be awesome.